# How to count the number of users with role = learner?

Tags: laravel

from this collection, I want to count and display the number of users which has the role of a learner

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => array:21 [▶]
  1 => array:21 [▶]
  2 => array:21 [▶]
  3 => array:21 [▶]
  4 => array:21 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "name" => "Learner"
    "last_name" => "Learner"
    "email" => "learner@app.com"
    "email_verified_at" => null
    "phone" => "3427932821"
    "type" => null
    "avatar" => "default.jpg"
    "gender" => null
    "identity" => null
    "street" => null
    "suburb" => null
    "city" => null
    "province" => null
    "code" => null
    "school" => null
    "grade" => null
    "subjects" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-10-21T11:48:11.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2020-10-21T11:48:11.000000Z"
    "roles" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:7 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "name" => "learner"
        "display_name" => "Learner"
        "description" => "Learner"
        "created_at" => "2020-10-21T11:48:11.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-10-21T11:48:11.000000Z"
        "pivot" => array:3 [▶]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  5 => array:21 [▶]
  6 => array:21 [▶]
]
```

here is my Usercontroller

```
public function index()
    {
      
        $users = User::with('roles')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();   

        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

I want to display the count result in the blade.php file... The number of users with a role that is equal to learner

Comment: Do you want to create a separate array for the same or you just want count?

Comment: Just like this ```$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($qw){$qw->whare('name', 'learner')})orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->count();```

Comment: Don't forget semicolon

Comment: @EncangCutbray Yes its working Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following snippet;

```
count(array_filter($user, function ($elem) {
    $roles = $elem['roles'];
    return count(array_filter($roles, function ($role) {
        return 'learner' === $role['name'];
    })) > 0;
}));
```